# Плавное появление второго слоя над первым из верхнего левого угла и смещающийся вниз по диагонали

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такое:

Есть фотка, скажем 400х300. Хочу сделать чтобы при наведении курсора появлялся над ним второй лайер(слой) такого же размера, НО(как?):

Чтобы он появлялся на нем же и сместился вниз по диагонали на 20 пикселей. С верхнего левого угла спустился по диагонали вниз на 20 пикселей. Как это можно реализовать? Хочу в основном через jQuery сделать.

Можете дать подсказку, как реализовать такое? Ну там мелочи знаю как сделать, главная проблема смещение после появления. Какие функции использовать и как?

Спасибо заранее.

**UPDATE**

```
 $(this).animate({
    'left':'-20px'
     },2000);
 });
```

Вот он смещает налево. А как по диагонали то???

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо! Преобразуйте комментарий свой в ответ чтобы я поставил вам палец вверх! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery не знаю, но что-то мне подсказывает, что

```
$(this).animate({
    'left':'-20px',
    'top':'+20px'
     },2000);
});
```

должно работать.